# What is one set of axioms which are sufficient for Calculus?

Tags: set-theory, peano-axioms, reverse-math

I am curious to find out what are the "minimum axioms" needed in order to be able to have highschool level math. Another way to explain it: if we were visited by a super intelligent race of aliens (assume no language barriers), which axioms would we have to give them in order for them to be able to start completely from scratch and come up with calculus as rigorously as possible? Would the axioms of logic, ZF axioms, Peano axioms be enough?

Comment: FOL+ZF is more than enough. Third-order arithmetic is probably fine.

Comment: Well, for calculus you might like some countable choice.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: For what, in particular? In most calculus cases I can think of offhand, it suffices to choose _rationals_, and those can be canonically well-ordered in ZF.

Comment: If _we_ are _visited by_ the aliens, I don't think we need to worry about teaching them calculus.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I recall reading that you need countable choice to prove sequential continuity equivalent to $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity. That might be slightly advanced for high school, though, depending.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Yeah, that is correct, but if your function is continuous everywhere, then you can still do this without any assumption of choice. But I agree that something that guarantees basic things like "easy recursive definitions" (read: DC) is probably a reasonable assumption.

Comment: By the way, the entire field of reverse mathematics is dedicated to these sort of questions.

Comment: There are good chances they already know PA, so use it for communicating when possible

Comment: @user1952009: Maybe they also know a proof of its inconsistency! :D

Comment: @AsafKaragila very sorry for tagging you in such an old question, but I was wondering, would you have any reference on how one could study how it could be possible with third-order arithmetic?

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, I think you would need at least [Peano's Axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html), set theory and predicate logic. Using them, I was able to formally construct the positive real numbers as Dedekind cuts.

The set theory should include rules for: subsets, power sets, Cartesian products, set equality, n-tuple equality, functions, pairwise and arbitrary union and choice.

Your predicate logic should include rules for equality, and allow quantification over sets and functions.

If your set theory included some kind of axiom of infinity (as does ZFC), you might be able to derive the Peano Axioms.

Comment: While this is somewhat related to OP's question, I don't think that it qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @Stefan If you want to derive calculus starting from a minimal list of axioms or rules, this is certainly a possible starting point. Again, I myself was able to go as far as formally constructing the positive real numbers using my of proof editing software with these rules and axioms built in -- a huge project (for me) requiring thousands of lines of formal proof. In my opinion, this list of rules and axioms seemed to me to be sufficient to eventually prove the FTC. What others do you think might be required?